# does eeprom_write_block function of avr.eeprom.h writes a NULL terminated string or we have to manually null terminate it

Tags: avr, eeprom

http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__eeprom.html

I am trying to figure out that if we use `eeprom_write_block` function or `eeprom_update_block` function do we need to manually null terminate it?

I came across [this tutorial on avr-freaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/tut-c-using-eeprom-memory-avr-gcc) where in one comment it is said that you have to read the strings and null terminate them but there is no word about writing. Couldnt get anything the avr-libc manual as well.

**UPDATE**

I have reserved some parts of eeprom using `EEMEM`  and they are strings. I am not sure how long the string would be except that it would be smaller than a max value. Now When I would read the string back from the eeprom I would just be reading the maximum number of bytes as again I would have no idea of the size of the string. If the eeprom has a null value at the end of the string when writing to it, the read string will have that null at the correct place.

**Situation**

I am saving mobile numbers of users as:

```
uint8_t EEMEM users[numberOfUsers][maxChar4Number];
```

Now when I get a number parsed and then save it to eeprom

```
#define eepu(message, EEADDR, BLKSIZE) eeprom_update_block((const void *)message, (void *)EEADDR, BLKSIZE);

eepu(user, users[0], strlen(user)); //strlen(user) will be less than the maxChar4Number
```

This will write the number to eeprom. When I read the i would be reading maxChar4Number bytes and a number could have been shorter than that length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a block which happens to be null-terminated, then reading it back should be fine. I do that when I want to save a filename in EEPROM. Just declare a suitable length (allowing room for the null terminator) and write the entire block to EEPROM.

Answer (score 1):

Since one normally does not know how long a character string is, we need a way to convey this information.  One technique used to avoid confusion is to add a NULL character (which is a zero) to the end of the string.  Another is to explicitly state how long the string is.

In the case of the function eeprom_write_block() talked about [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/EEPROMWriteAnything), we see that we are formally passing not only a pointer to the string but also the size of the string.

Comment: I am using `  eeprom_read_block((void*)&settings, (void*)0, sizeof(settings));`. it has the size argument . do I need to Null terminate??

Comment: I have reserved some parts of eeprom using `EEMEM`  and they are strings. I am not sure how long the string would be except that it would be smaller than a max value. Now When I would read the string back from the eeprom I would just be reading the maximum number of bytes as again I would have no idea of the size of the string.

Comment: I would think you do not need a NULL at the end of your character string for the eeprom_read_block() method as you are telling it how many characters you are reading.  I don't think you need it for the sizeof() method call either as sizeof() uses the type of the argument.  That said, I believe you will always read the size of your array number of characters from EEPROM.  Is that what you want?